# First-chance exception at 0x0435A072 (mfc110d.dll) in MRISegmentation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have converted visual studio 10 program to visual studio 12. The program built successfully but when i tried to run it. I am getting error if (!pThread->InitInstance()) here . pThread is null.

I tried to search the point from where it is called. But I dont know every time I tried to debug it, its directly going to the winmain.cpp and getting the pThread null error.  I am posting the code of my main file and header file here.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MRISegmentation.h"
#include "MRISegmentationDlg.h"

 #ifdef _DEBUG
 #define new DEBUG_NEW
 #endif


     // CMRISegmentationApp

 BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMRISegmentationApp, CWinApp)
ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, CWinApp::OnHelp)
  END_MESSAGE_MAP()


 // CMRISegmentationApp construction

 CMRISegmentationApp::CMRISegmentationApp()
  {


// TODO: add construction code here,
// Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only CMRISegmentationApp object

CMRISegmentationApp theApp;

// CMRISegmentationApp initialization

BOOL CMRISegmentationApp::InitInstance()

{    
InitCommonControls();

CWinApp::InitInstance();

AfxEnableControlContainer();
// Standard initialization
// If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
// of your final executable, you should remove from the following
// the specific initialization routines you do not need
// Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
// TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
// such as the name of your company or organization
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

CMRISegmentationDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
if (nResponse == IDOK)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with OK
}
else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
{
    // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
    //  dismissed with Cancel
}

// Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
//  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
return FALSE;
 }

 And the header file  "MRISegmentation.h" is below

 #pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
#error include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols


// CMRISegmentationApp:
// See MRISegmentation.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

class CMRISegmentationApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
CMRISegmentationApp();

 // Overrides
public:
virtual BOOL InitInstance();

 // Implementation

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
 };

 extern CMRISegmentationApp theApp;
```

Comment: You have a null pointer somewhere. Enable break on Access violation in your Debug -> Exceptions to have it stop at the location. Then walk up the callstack to your code when it stops.

Comment: `m_pMainWnd = &dlg;` remember that after the dialog closes `m_pMainWnd ` will be garbage.

Comment: I am getting the access violation in winmain.cpp in this line.                    if (!pThread->InitInstance())   so whenever I am running it gets the violation here.

Comment: Walk up the callstack to your code. The callstack should be in a combo box on the toolbar.

Comment: If there is none of your code in the callstack the bug is likely in code that you did not show.

Comment: this is what showing in call stack            

 mfc110d.dll!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 37 C++
  MRISegmentation.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26 C++
  MRISegmentation.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 528 C
  MRISegmentation.exe!WinMainCRTStartup() Line 377 C
  kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown

Comment: It's likely you have a problem in `CMRISegmentationDlg` constructor or `CMRISegmentationDlg::OnInitDialog`. Show what you have in there. Call stack shows a bunch of information, it should point to other files like `MRISegmentation.cpp` (or whatever you called your file) - Don't post code in comments, put additional information in your question.

Comment: @ShrabaniGhosh please don't put clarifications in comments (it's illegible), but [edit]  your question instead.